# Проблема с выводом колличества записей через произвольные записи

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Вопрос по Wordpress.
Сталкнулась с проблемой выводом своих зареганых записей. 
Искала ответ в гугле,ну чет не гуглится, может кто то сталкивался.

Суть в чем, после зарегистриваного типа записей, я установила advanced custom fields, проблем не в нем,но все же. В моем новом типе записей я могу добавить сколько угодно записей, НО проблема в том, что показывается на сайте ЛИШЬ 5 записей. Хотя в админке пишешся что запись опубликована. В чем может проблема быть?

Заранее Всем спасибо за ответ!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы код покажите, каким выводите. Там, скорее всего, get_posts(), а в нем по умолчанию ограничение на 5 записей. Используйте numberposts = -1

Answer (score 1):

В итоге,оказалось все банально просто, нужно добавить в $args

```
'posts_per_page' => '-1'
```

И все в итоге появилось и заработало.